# Why does the script stop working?It should work

Tags: autohotkey

Code
    WheelUp::
    MouseGetPos, MouseX, MouseY
    PixelGetColor, color, %MouseX%, %MouseY%
    if (color = 0x282828)
    {
    Send, {sc149}
    }
    Else if (color <> 0x282828)
    {
        Click, WheelUp
    }
    return

```
WheelDown::
MouseGetPos, MouseX, MouseY
PixelGetColor, color, %MouseX%, %MouseY%
if (color = 0x282828)
{
    Send, {sc151}
}
Else if (color <> 0x282828)
{
    Click, WheelDown
}
return
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions *seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?")* must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The code seems correct. But what does it mean that it stops working? Is it working on certain windows but not in others? If that's the case you might need to run the script as admin.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are trying to search for a certain color in the screen whilst scrolling up or down respectively. However, `Click, WheelDown` doesn't trigger your own AHK Hotkey, so you won't have a recursive hotkey, in order to solve this issue, you may explicitly execute the corresponding hotkey by using the `Goto` keyword:

```
WheelDown::
MouseGetPos, MouseX, MouseY
PixelGetColor, color, %MouseX%, %MouseY%
if (color = 0x282828) {
    Send, {sc151}
}
Else if (color <> 0x282828) {
    Click, WheelDown
    Goto, WheelDown
}
return
```

As for further optimization, I would strongly recommend using a while loop, which its usage is shown in the following code:

```
WheelUp::
w_up_stop := False
w_down_stop := True
ToolTip, Scrolling up
while (color <> 0x282828 and !w_up_stop) {
MouseGetPos, MouseX, MouseY
    PixelGetColor, color, %MouseX%, %MouseY%
    Click, WheelUp
}
Send, {sc149}
return

WheelDown::
w_up_stop := True
w_down_stop := False
ToolTip, Scrolling Down
while (color <> 0x282828 and !w_down_stop) {
    MouseGetPos, MouseX, MouseY
    PixelGetColor, color, %MouseX%, %MouseY%
    Click, WheelDown
}
Send, {sc151}
return
```

Also, I would add a hotkey to break the loop in case you can't find the color you are searching for:

```
#If w_down_stop or w_up_stop
Esc::
w_down_stop := False
w_up_stop := False
```